# Apache Spark how to concatenate (multiple) indexers and encoders into a pipeline

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Before I can use a machine learning model on my current dataframe I have to apply a couple of preprocessing steps. This includes the conversion of several categorial columns to index columns with `StringIndexer`s and encoding the **new** columns with `OneHotEncoder`s.

I want to put all transformation methods in a pipeline to persist it and apply it easily on incoming data. But since the indexed columns do not exist yet, calling the `fit()` method on the encoders fails.

How can I create a pipeline that consists of all these steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can threat both – indexers and encoders – as `PipelineStage`s add them to your pipeline and fit the whole pipeline in one step. Example:

```
String INDEX_APPENDIX = "_IDX";
String VECTOR_APPENDIX = "_VEC";
ArrayList<PipelineStage> stages = new ArrayList<>();

for (String column : Arrays.asList("col1", "col2" )) {
        stages.add(new StringIndexer().setInputCol(column).setOutputCol(column + INDEX_APPENDIX));
        stages.add(new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol(column + INDEX_APPENDIX).setOutputCol(column +
                VECTOR_APPENDIX));
    }

Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
    .setStages(stages.toArray(new PipelineStage[stages.size()]));

Dataset<Row> processedDf = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df);
```